# Filtering Aggregate root entity and child entity by a property on the child entity

Tags: linq, frameworks, filter, entity

Hope that someone out there can help with this!

I'll give an example based on the standard Order-->OrderLine-->Product rather than the actual situation to make it easier to explain!

Basically, I want to run a query that returns all orders for which there is an order line containing a TV.  Simple enough:

```
IEnumerable<Order> orders;
          using (var context = new DataContext())
          {
              var source =
                  context.Orders.Include("OrderLines").Include(
                      "OrderLines.Product");

              orders= source.Where(o => o.OrderLines.Where(ol => ol.Product.Name == "TV")).ToList();
          }
          return orders;
```

This works in the sense that I get the correct collection of Order entities, but when I use look at each Order's collection of OrderLines it contains **all** OrderLines not just those containing at TV.

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I does make sense in that the query is fulfilling your original criteria "to return all orders for which there is an order line containing a TV", each order will of course have all the orderlines. The filter is only being used to select the Orders, not the OrderLines.

To retrieve just the OrderLines containing TV from an Order you'd use the filter again, thus:

```
var OrderLinesWithTV = order.OrderLines.Where(ol => ol.Product.Name == "TV");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Is there any way of filtering the OrderLines for all Orders in one statement, rather that looping through the collection of orders and filtering the orderlines for each individually?

Comment: The only way I can think of approaching the state you have is to retrieve all the OrderLines with "TV" directly from the OrderLines collection (for the entire entity set of OrderLines, not related to Order, i.e. `dbContext.OrderLines.Where(ol => ol.Product.Name == "TV")`) and then step up to each order. In just the same way as tabular data from a SQL query you will see the same Order for many OrderLines and if you used `ReturnedOrderLine.Order.OrderLines` then you'd see the full set of OrderLines for that Order. The issue is that you are applying a filter to the query not the result.

Comment: Went for the two stage process in the end, retrieving matching orders with all the order lines and then looping through each order and filtering the orderlines down to the one of interest.  It seems a bit inefficient as I'm getting more data than I need from the database and then filtering it in memory, but it works!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Might not be as bad as you think if it's lazy loading.

Answer (score 1):

The main point is to know if you need to keep (or not) a reference to the order header in the filtered lines.
I.e. do you want the list of all the orders with a TV, and more precisely only their TV lines ? or do you want all the TV lines nevermind their order header ?

You seem to prefer the first option.
Then the best solution would certainly be

```
var relevantOrders = orders.Where(order => order.OrderLines.Any(ol => ol.Product.Name == "TV"))
```

to get the relevant orders, and then, for each order in relevantOrders :

```
order.OrderLines.Where(ol => ol.Product.Name == "TV")
```

to consider only the TV lines.

Other techniques would result in a loss of information or force you to build a new orders collection similar to the initial one but double-filtered on the headers and on the lines, which seems fairly bad as far as elegance and performance is concerned.